# Stress of calling SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime' every 10 seconds

Tags: mysql

As above, do you think a connection that is calling that query continuously, for the entire connection's existence, will cause stress on the server in the long term? The reason why I am doing this is because my mysql module for some reason drops connection after about 5 minutes of inactivity. I've tried changing the server settings to no avail, and this is my hacky solution.

Comment: No Problem. But you should better take care of the actual problem. If your application uses multiple connections (from a pool) there might be connections that timeout anyway, no matter if you run 100 queries per second.

Comment: It's not my module, so I can't exactly do anything about it. Not only that, but I've spoken to the developer of the module, and shown him my code. He has no idea why it's happening. Another one of my peers recommended that I try a few different mysql modules and change the way my wrapper structure works to see if that fixes the problem, but if I can just do it this way that seems to be fine. Maximum amount of queries that will feasibly happen in my use case is at most, 25.